# how do i download adobe flash on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, flash

I am very new to Ubuntu and I am trying to download Adobe Flash Player. I need someone to take me through every single step. What version do I need to download? 
Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is only one step. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

or use Ubuntu Software Center.